# Case expression to return value with two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I need to return the initial AAALTLCHANGEREASON value when AAALTLCHANGEVALUE is equal to 'Manual Rate'. So in this example I need 'Class needed' returned.

```
AAALTLCHANGEVALUE   AAALTLCHANGEREASON         CREATEDDATETIME     
ManualCoded              New Customer           09/17/2019          
Manual Rate              Class needed           09/18/2019
CWI Inspection           Reweigh                09/19/2019
Manual Rate              Insurance Added        09/20/2019
```

I've tried this case expression with no success:

```
case

when  [AAALTLCHANGEVALUE] = 'manual rate' then[AAALTLCHANGEREASON]
when  [AAALTLCHANGEVALUE] = 'manual rate' then MIN[CREATEDDATETIME]

else null

end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `CASE` expression. There are no `Case` Statements in T-SQL.

Comment: Your current CASE expression checks to see if `AAALTLCHANGEVALUE` is `manual rate` and then does something... then it checks for the same exact thing again? That second condition will never fire since it was already `manual rate` for the first condition. Perhaps I'm not understanding what you want. Can you share your desired results from that sample data (and perhaps beef up the sample data with more examples so we can understand better)?

Comment: Larnu, semantics are not relevant to my question. I need help with the syntax/logic.

Comment: Can you add your desired output, so anyway the statement makes no sense, sorry, at the moment you will never get the CreationDate, you have to separate your CASEs...

Comment: Semantics is always important otherwise we dont know what is your logic

Comment: I have to agree, the "semantics" of that comment are literally related to the fact that your second piece of logic could never fire; thus, either your question is incorrect or your example is incorrect, and it prevents us from being able to accurately assist.

Answer (score 1):

First you select all  `'Manual Rate'` and then make sure no one else is early than that row.

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/260d7c/2)**

```
 SELECT AAALTLCHANGEREASON
 FROM YourTable t1
 WHERE AAALTLCHANGEVALUE = 'Manual Rate'
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM YourTable t2
                   WHERE t2.CREATEDDATETIME < t1.CREATEDDATETIME
                     AND AAALTLCHANGEVALUE = 'Manual Rate')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top` and `order by`:

```
select TOP AAALTLCHANGEREASON
from t
where AAALTLCHANGEVALUE = 'manual rate'
order by CREATEDDATETIME;
```